# Conditional referene in field of sequelize model

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js

I have a field which can have primary key of any of two tables: Table A or table B.

Is there any way of defining reference in such a way that it will pick up the reference conditionally?

I looked into the [model docs of sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html). But there is no such feature specified.

I don't even know if something like this is possible:

```
const providerMapping = vProviders.defineModel('vProviderMapping', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        field: 'Id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    type: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'Type'
    },
    referencedId: {//can have pk of any of the two tables
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        field: 'ReferenceId',
       //reference based on a condition. type: A
        references: {
            model: A,
            key: id
        }
        //or reference based on a condition. type: B
        //{
        //    model: B,
        //    key: id
        //}
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by pick up a reference conditionally? As in, you want a column to be a foreign key, but only check the constraint if some other condition is met? If so, no; you should be using 2 different columns (1 which a foreign key, and the other which isn't).

Comment: @Larnu. Thank you for your response. As in, you want a column to be a foreign key, but only check the constraint if some other condition is met? Basically Yes. I think you might be right here. I might need to use two columns. So there is basically no way to do this with only one column?

Comment: If you have a Foreign Key on a column, you can either have it be trusted, and have it be checked, or be untrusted, and not be checked, and that setting is at the column, not row. If you are inserting values in a column that is a foreign key, but the value doesn't appear in the foreign table, it's not a foreign key any more. #

Answer (score 0):

@alchi
Actually you cannot do what you are expecting to do now. When you do references in model that means you are creating a foreign key. However when you define a foreign key, it means that  this column is referencing the primary key of a particular table. Hence you cannot refer the same column to two different table. You can actually achieve this by creating two columns if you want to define the reference in the model.

However, you don't need to create this reference in the model if you want to multipurpose the column to have primary keys of both tables. You can do so just by using your logic. Also you can still connect the two tables using model relation functions like belongsTo/ hasOne etc. when you want to join your data in your logic.